# Question about graphs and relations

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, relations

If I have a directed graph $G = (V,E)$, let the relation $R$= {$(a,b)$ | $a$ has a directed path to $b$} be a relation over $V$.

How can I prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation, partial order, and total (if any are true)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R$ is clearly not in general an equivalence relation, because it’s not in general symmetric: just look at the directed graph $\bullet\longrightarrow\bullet$. On the other hand, you can’t count on its being antisymmetric, either: $\bullet\longleftrightarrow\bullet$. And it certainly needn’t be total: $\bullet\qquad\bullet$.

Comment: So all are false?

Comment: @Jose: Each of them may be true of a particular directed graph (assuming that you allow paths of length $0$), but none of them is true of **all** directed graphs.

Comment: @Jose: My answer contains very simple counterexamples for all three.